# Duplicar listas de elementos [a,b] cuando un elemento se repite a . Python

Tags: python, ordenamiento, datos, conjuntos, ordenar

Pongamos que tenemos un conjunto de elementos `[a,b]` ordenado:

*Conjunto inicial*

```
[[1,5],[2,5],[3,5],[3,6],[4,5]]
```

Como me interesa que los conjuntos sean de 4 elementos, y veo que el elemento 2 y 3 tienen el mismo valor de `a` quisiera saber como escribir un programa que parta del conjunto inicial y haga  lo siguiente:

*Conjunto 1*

```
[[1,5],[2,5],[3,5],[4,5]]
```

*Conjunto 2*

```
[[1,5],[2,5],[3,6],[4,5]]
```

Si por ejemplo el conjunto inicial fuese:

```
[[1,5],[2,5],[3,5],[3,6],[4,5],[4,6]]
```

El programa deberia retornar:

```
[[1,5],[2,5],[3,5],[4,5]]
[[1,5],[2,5],[3,5],[4,6]]
[[1,5],[2,5],[3,6],[4,5]]
[[1,5],[2,5],[3,6],[4,6]]
```

¿Existe alguna manera en python de realizar esto? He probado a utilizar el modulo `combinations` y `permutations` pero me parece que es excesivo para la simpleza de la tarea.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrias ser más especifico en lo que quieres ?,

Comment: Si, que dada una lista de elementos tipo`[a,b]` como por ejemplo `[[1,5],[2,5],[3,5],[3,6],[4,5]]`, se puede observar que hay dos elementos en los que el `3` se repite, por lo que me gustaria hacer que esa lista se convirtiese en 2 listas, una con cada elemento repetido: Lista 1 = `[[1,5],[2,5],[3,5],[4,5]]` y Lista 2 = `[[1,5],[2,5],[3,6],[4,5]]` . Como puedes ver, ahora en ninguna de las dos listas se repite el valor `a` de cada elemento.

Comment: Pero en la pregunta parece que consideras repetición tanto `a` como `b`. ¿Qué pasa con el `5` repetido en las segundas posiciones?¿Qué esperas obtener como resultado?

Comment: @ChemaCortes Me acabo de dar cuenta, ya lo he editado, me refiero solo a si se repite `a`

Answer (score 1):

Editado: aunque no se especifica en el enunciado, se da por supuesto que la lista está ordenada por el primer elemento de las tuplas antes de que actúe `sortby()`. Si no fuera así, sería preciso ordenarla la lista primero:

```py
lst = sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(0))
```

---

Se puede hacer con el *supermódulo* [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html).

Primero hacemos una **agrupación según el primer item** de cada tupla, y después hacemos el **producto cartesiano**:

```py
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby, product

def duple(lst):
   grupos = (list(v) for k,v in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0)))
   return [list(x) for x in product(*grupos)]
```

Comprobamos:

```py
>>> for l in duple([[1,5],[2,5],[3,5],[3,6],[4,5]]): print(l)
[[1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 5]]
[[1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 5]]
>>> for l in duple([[1,5],[2,5],[3,5],[3,6],[4,5],[4,6]]): print(l)
[[1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 5]]
[[1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 6]]
[[1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 5]]
[[1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 6]]
```

Para entenderlo mejor, podemos ir paso por paso:

Usamos `itemgetter(0)` en `groupby` para indicar que queremos hacer las agrupaciones por el primer item de cada elemento de la lista.

El resultado se puede ver mejor si pasamos a una lista:

```py
lst = [[1,5],[2,5],[3,5],[3,6],[4,5]]

grupos = [list(v) for k,v in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0))]
print(grupos)

>>> [[[1, 5]], [[2, 5]], [[3, 5], [3, 6]], [[4, 5]]]
```

Tenemos en esta lista agrupadas las tuplas según su primer elemento. Lo siguiente es hacer el **producto cartesiano**:

```py
from itertools import product

resultado = list(product(*grupos))

>>> [([1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 5]), ([1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 5])]
```

O sea:

```latex
[[1, 5]]  X  [[2, 5]]  X  [[3, 5], [3, 6]]  X  [[4, 5]]
```

Comment: +1 Wow! Todo lo que se hace con solo dos líneas. ¡Inténtalo a base de bucles! XD

Comment: Con recursividad también saldría (⌐■_■)